# Como puedo hacer que Django me redirija a un home diferente dependiendo de mi tipo de usuario

Tags: python, django

Tengo enlazado el User a una tabla de "tipo de usuario" donde un usuario puede ser de varios tipos de usuario en este caso :

> models.py

```
class tipoUsuario(models.Model):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_sip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_assesor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

y quiero hacer que, dependiendo de los tipos de usuarios marcados me redirija a un "home" diferente, como puedo hacer esa dirección?
Si es maestro me muestre un home, si es maestro y asesor a otro y si es estudiante a otro. Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta y tengas oportunidad de recibir ayuda, considera leer [ask], intentar algo y centrar tu pregunta en algo mas concreto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la función redirect y validar el tipo de usuario que inicio sesión:

- Defines las rutas necesarias para cada rol:

> url.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('teacher/', views.teacher_home, name='teacher_home'),
    path('student/', views.student_home, name='student_home'),
    path('techer-assesor/', views.teacher_assesor_home, name='teacher_assesor_home')
]
```

Luego declaras tus vistas en los archivos correspondientes a la estructura de tu proyecto:

> APP/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_student:
        return redirect('student_home')
    elif request.user.is_teacher and request.user.is_assesor:
        return redirect('teacher_assesor_home')
    elif request.user.is_teacher:
        return redirect("teacher_home")
    else:
        # Return por defecto o Elevar un error
        return HttpResponse("DEFAULT")


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def teacher_home(requet):
    return render("teacher_home.html")

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def student_home(requet):
    return render("student_home.html")

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def teacher_assesor_home(requet):
    return render("teacher_assesor_home.html")
```